# How to load a resource name procedurally?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, r.java-file

A little context, I'm using Eclipse to write an android game/app using Java. One function returns a variable "flag" which tells a render function to draw a window on top of the screen. My code looks like this:

```
if(flag == 3000){
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_3000));}

else if(flag == 3001){
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_3001));}

else if(flag == 3002){
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_3002));}

else if(flag == 3003){
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_3003));}

else if(flag == 3004){
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_3004));}
```

It would be nice if I could simply do all of this with one line. It would be something like (from Flash actionscript)

```
if(flag >= 3000){
    window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, escape("R.drawable.tutorialdiagram_" + flag)));
}
```

I'm sure there is a super easy way to do this. I should have learned it on day 1, etc. Who can be the first to school me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (replace "my.package" with your package name):

```
int id = res.getIdentifier("tutorialdiagram_" + flag, "drawable", "my.package");
window.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,id));
```

Comment: Oh my god, it worked on the first try! Thanks! I had to have the package name in quotes, by the way. I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: Now if another programmer sees my code, and sees that part, I don't have to be totally embarrassed. LOL

Comment: Is there a similar function for strings?  For example, to shorten this using the flag variable?
res.getString(R.string.flag_1);

Comment: Same thing, just pass "string" instead of "drawable".